# apt-cache search does not find g++ packages

Tags: 16.04, apt

When I run `apt-cache search g++-6` , nothing comes up.

However, in Synaptic, I can find `g++-6` just fine. Is this a bug with `apt-cache`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g++-6` is not available in Ubuntu 16.04, (I don't have it  in synaptic either).

However try escaping `+` sign, it works for me:

```
apt-cache search "g\+\+-5"
```

or for `g++-6`:

```
apt-cache search "g\+\+-6"
```

It's because of "regex", `man apt-cache`:

```
search regex...
    search performs a full text search on all available package lists 
    for the POSIX regex pattern given.
```

---

Your string after `apt-cache search` will be considered as a "regex" so by:

```
g++-6
```

you are looking for at least one or more "g" followed by a "-" and followed by a 6, something like "g-6" or "gg-6" or "ggg-6" ... so your search brings you no result.